# Перевод string в float c++/cli

Tags: visual-studio, строки, c++-cli, float

Не могу никак перевести `string` в `float`. В методичке написан метод `StrToFloat()`, но в моей Visual Studio 2017 это не воспринимается. Подскажите какой метод в C++/CLI использовать для этой операции.

Через strof тоже не работает

```
float f1 = strtof( textBox1->Text);
```

> [image: идентификатор "StrToFloat" не определен]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `StrToFloat` - это борландовская ф-ция. `atof` нужна (и стандартная библиотека). А да... `float::Parse` для `с++/cli` или что-то такое.

Comment: Картинка с ошибкой студии, конечно, полезна, но надо ещё и код приводить в текстовом виде в вопросе.

Comment: Поддерживаю, Сайт SO хорошо подсвечивает синтаксиз языка для текста, публиковать картинку не нужно, вместо картинки нужно публиковать сам текст.

Comment: `private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
 float f1 = StrToFloat(textBox1->Text);
 }`

Comment: Вам нужно преобразовать строк в число или число в строку? А то в заголовке одно, в теле вопроса другое

Comment: Извиняюсь, нужно строку в число переобразовать

Comment: Если вы хотите опубликовать текст в вопросе - нажмите ссылку править на вопросе, и вставьте. Для Подстветки синтаксиза нужно дополнительно добавить по 4 проблела отсуп слева.

Comment: Где методичку взяли? Препод в учебном заведении выдал? Вот для начала у него и поинтересуйтесь, какой фреймворк вы должны использовать. Потому что если вы должны использовать `StrToFloat`, то зачем взяли язык C++/CLI (это не C++, это совсем другой язык) и библиотеку WinForms.

Comment: Раз уж вы используете C++/CLI, то смотрите документацию платформы .NET. Вам в первом же комментарии правильно предложили `float::Parse`.

Comment: В том то и дело что сказано работать в с++ билдере, а он у меня на 7ку не ставится. Решил за альтернативу юзать студию микромягких но теперь небольшие проблемы с синтаксисом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Придумал альтернативу в виде перевода float в double (для меня это не критично) и последующее использование

`double f1 = Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Text);`

Comment: `Convert::ToSingle`